# IIOP Client Authentication and ProgrammaticLogin in Glassfish v3

Tags: java, glassfish, corba

In Glassfish v2 I secure my JNDI lookups by enabling the "IIOP Client Authentication" checkbox in the admin console under the ORB node.

In my standalone client I then perform a "ProgrammaticLogin", which then allows me to do JNDI lookups.

In Glassfish v3 however, I get this error if want to do any JNDI lookups in the same setup:

```
18.08.2010 14:31:10 com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified
initDelegates INFO: Using
com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate
as the delegate
org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION:
----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION: 
vmcid: 0x0 
minor code: 0 
completed: No
```

I am pretty sure the "ProgrammaticLogin" works in general, since it allows me to do remote method calls on my secured EJB's (using `@RolesAllowed` but if the IIOP Client Auth is turned off).

The user I login with is a simple user that I created for the "file" realm.

Any ideas, why the ProgrammticLogin fails to work in Glassfish v3 for authorizing JNDI lookups?

Or what is the correct way to authenticate with the ORB from a standalone client; for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure appserv-rt.jar is on your classpath? It is part of every glassfish3 installation e.g. at my installation it is located here:

```
/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/lib
```

This is very important. It contains some client java classes especially: AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.

These add a SecClientRequestInterceptor to the ORB which cares that the username and password is added to the GIOP request sent to the server.

It took me about two days of scanning the source code of glassfish and sniffing the corba packages on the wire with wireshark until I found this.

An example how to secure a bean and write a real Java EE client can be found here:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbzk/index.html

Hope this helps
    Manuel